# How to make a specify undirected edge be a directed with a elegant method?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Suppose I have such undirected garph.

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 4, 2 <-> 5, 4 <-> 5}, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

If I want to make `{1 <-> 2,2 <-> 5}` to be `{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 2}`
[image]

This is current solution:

```
Graph[Join[
  If[MemberQ[
      DirectedEdges @@@ 
       Sort /@ {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 2}, 
      DirectedEdges @@ Sort[#]], Nothing, #] & /@ 
   EdgeList[g], {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 2}], 
 VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Any elegant method can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
EdgeAdd[EdgeDelete[g,{1 <-> 2,2 <-> 5}],{DirectedEdge[1,2], DirectedEdge[5,2]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Oh,God!Some dog blood in my brain maybe. :)